# Normal looping or looping over indiced list -Difference

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

what's the difference between looping over list this way

```
for i in lst :
   print("Do something")
```

and this way

```
for i in lst[:] :
    print("do something")
```

Comment: `[:]` makes a copy of the orginal list

Comment: One prints `"Do something"` over and over again, and the other prints the elements of `lst`.

Comment: Generally, if you want to mutate/modify the list while you are looping through the list items you can use the second syntax otherwise stick with first.

Comment: In your first example, for every element in *lst*, the string 'Do something' will be emitted to the standard output stream.  In your second example, for every element in a copy of *lst*, the string 'Do something' will be emitted to the standard output stream.